# How can I reset my xwindows settings to defaults?

Tags: 10.04, xorg, flash

I recently tried to plug my Ubuntu machine into my TV via a VGA cable. I just plugged it in and rebooted to see if Xwindows could handle it without any tweaking (it couldn't). This wasn't a big deal, but it seems to have screwed something up. I unplugged the tv and plugged my monitor back in and rebooted, but now I cannot use full-screen Flash at all. If I pull up (for example) a Youtube video and click the full-screen button, the screen flashes, then goes back to firefox, and the embedded video disappears and is replaced with a tan box. I've included the errors I get when I run firefox from a terminal below.

```
*** NSPlugin Viewer  *** WARNING: unhandled variable 18 (<unknown variable>) in NPN_GetValue()
*** NSPlugin Viewer  *** WARNING: unhandled variable 18 (<unknown variable>) in NPN_GetValue()
*** NSPlugin Viewer  *** WARNING: unhandled variable 18 (<unknown variable>) in NPN_GetValue()
*** NSPlugin Wrapper *** ERROR: NPP_Write() wait for reply: Connection reset by peer
*** NSPlugin Wrapper *** WARNING:(/build/buildd/nspluginwrapper-1.2.2/src/npw-wrapper.c:2235):invoke_NPP_DestroyStream: assertion failed: (rpc_method_invoke_possible(plugin->connection))
*** NSPlugin Wrapper *** WARNING:(/build/buildd/nspluginwrapper-1.2.2/src/npw-wrapper.c:2119):invoke_NPP_URLNotify: assertion failed: (rpc_method_invoke_possible(plugin->connection))
*** NSPlugin Wrapper *** WARNING:(/build/buildd/nspluginwrapper-1.2.2/src/npw-wrapper.c:1923):invoke_NPP_SetWindow: assertion failed: (rpc_method_invoke_possible(plugin->connection))
*** NSPlugin Wrapper *** WARNING:(/build/buildd/nspluginwrapper-1.2.2/src/npw-wrapper.c:2533):invoke_NPP_HandleEvent: assertion failed: (rpc_method_invoke_possible(plugin->connection))
*** NSPlugin Wrapper *** ERROR: NPObject 0x7f61348a9890 is no longer valid!
*** NSPlugin Wrapper *** ERROR: NPObject 0x7f61348a9890 is no longer valid!
*** NSPlugin Wrapper *** ERROR: NPObject 0x7f61348a9890 is no longer valid!
*** NSPlugin Wrapper *** ERROR: NPObject 0x7f61348a9890 is no longer valid!
*** NSPlugin Wrapper *** ERROR: NPObject 0x7f61348a9890 is no longer valid!
*** NSPlugin Wrapper *** ERROR: NPObject 0x7f61348a9890 is no longer valid!
*** NSPlugin Wrapper *** ERROR: NPObject 0x7f61348a9890 is no longer valid!
*** NSPlugin Wrapper *** ERROR: NPObject 0x7f61348a9890 is no longer valid!
*** NSPlugin Wrapper *** ERROR: NPObject 0x7f61348a9890 is no longer valid!
*** NSPlugin Wrapper *** ERROR: NPObject 0x7f61348a9890 is no longer valid!
*** NSPlugin Wrapper *** WARNING:(/build/buildd/nspluginwrapper-1.2.2/src/npw-wrapper.c:2533):invoke_NPP_HandleEvent: assertion failed: (rpc_method_invoke_possible(plugin->connection))
*** NSPlugin Wrapper *** WARNING:(/build/buildd/nspluginwrapper-1.2.2/src/npw-wrapper.c:1854):invoke_NPP_Destroy: assertion failed: (rpc_method_invoke_possible(plugin->connection))
*** NSPlugin Wrapper *** ERROR: NPObject 0x7f6136861b60 is no longer valid!
*** NSPlugin Wrapper *** WARNING:(/build/buildd/nspluginwrapper-1.2.2/src/npw-wrapper.c:1854):invoke_NPP_Destroy: assertion failed: (rpc_method_invoke_possible(plugin->connection))
*** NSPlugin Wrapper *** ERROR: NPObject 0x7f61348a9890 is no longer valid!
```

Is there any way for me to just rerun the X setup bits of the Ubuntu installation to get back my orignal setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sudo apt-get purge xorg && sudo apt-get install xorg` should remove xorg and all it's configuration files and reinstall it.

Comment: Hmm. I ran this, but it doesn't appear to have brought back my full-screen flash. What other settings could have been screwed up by trying the different screen? Gnome settings? edit: I went ahead and gave you the "answer" flag since you did answer the question I asked

Comment: I looks like a flash problem, have you tried to reinstall flashplugin-installer with the same commands as above?

Comment: I did try that, without any luck. Could it be Gnome? Not sure how to easily wipe that out... I did try temporarily removing all gnome-related folders in my home directory to lose any personal settings, but that had no effect on the flash issue.

Comment: I think a lot of the Gnome settings are saved in ~/.config and ~/.cache, but there are a lot of other things there too so be careful.